# Is there a way to iterate through the fields in a row of a PXResultSet?

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to use a foreach loop in a BLC to iterate through the fields of a PXResultSet to get the FieldNames?

Is this doable?  I can't seem to find a good way.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The `PXResultset` records are selected from a view. You can get the field names from the `View`.

Here's a full example:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // Get field list from data view
        var dataView = new PXSelect<SOOrder>(Base);
        string fieldNames = string.Join(",", GetFieldNames(dataView.View, Base.Caches));
          
        // You don't need result set to get field names
        PXResultset<SOOrder> resultSet = dataView.Select();
                   
        throw new PXException(fieldNames);
    }

    public string[] GetFieldNames(PXView view, PXCacheCollection caches)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var set = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (Type t in view.GetItemTypes())
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                list.AddRange(caches[t].Fields);
                set.AddRange(list);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string field in caches[t].Fields)
                {
                    string s = String.Format("{0}__{1}", t.Name, field);

                    if (set.Add(s))
                    {
                        list.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

When run, this example will show the fields names used in the data view in Sales Order screen SO301000 as an exception.
[image]

Field names are contained in `Cache` object. If you really need to get field names from PXResultset you need to iterate the cache types in the result set.

Example for first DacType (0) of result set:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        var dataView = new PXSelect<SOOrder>(Base);
        PXResultset<SOOrder> resultSet = dataView.Select();
        
        foreach (PXResult result in resultSet)
        {
            Type dacType = result.GetItemType(0);

            foreach (var field in Base.Caches[dacType].Fields)
                PXTrace.WriteInformation(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again, Hugues...  ;D